# How do I insert space in Jinja template for loop?

Tags: jquery, textarea, jinja2

I populate textarea with

`textarea.value='{%for i in range(0,3)%}{{data[i][0]}}{% endfor %}'`.

But It produces string without spaces in between `i` so the output is like 
`firstsecondthird`. I'd like it to be `first second third`.

What are the ways to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

...it can be done by `{%for i in range(0,3)%}{{data[i][0]+" "}}`

As per Jinja documentation:

> `+` Adds two objects together. Usually the objects are numbers but if both are strings or lists you can concatenate them this way.

Answer (score 6):

You need to do it outside the calculation part:

```
textarea.value='{%for i in range(0,3)%}{{data[i][0]}} {% endfor %}'
```

Notice the space after `{{data[i][0]}}`

Comment: Your answer is correct and in line with Jinja2 guidelines.